# Structured reference table - Maximum with criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have a structured reference table:

```
Date    Hours    
10/20   12
10/20   15
10/21   6
10/21   10
10/21   12
10/22   10
```

I would like to create a calculated column that finds the max hours for each date:

```
Date    Hours  maxhours  
10/20   12     15
10/20   15     15 
10/21   6      12
10/21   10     12
10/21   12     12
10/22   10     10
```

I tried various combinations of max, index, match; but I'm unable to get the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mahesh, I wasn't adding extra information. I was answering my own question (Q&A style). If you have an edit to my answer post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{=MAX(IF([@Date]=[Date],[Hours],""))}
```

Must be entered as an array formula.

```
Date    Hours  maxhours  
10/20   12     15
10/20   15     15 
10/21   6      12
10/21   10     12
10/21   12     12
10/22   10     10
```